# data preprocessing with zeros dominating

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, data-preprocessing

I'm working on a machine learning classification project and i faced some difficulties: all of my features distributed like this: [image: distribution]

I'm not sure what should i do, should i use any scalers/other preprocessing methods? All features means count of some events for a specific person. What problems can this distribution cause after fitting the models? Also, is there any name for this kind of distribution?

Comment: There’s no obvious reason that this should be a problem. Is there a specific difficulty you’ve encountered or concern that you can articulate?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is the problem. If you're feeling paranoid, you could check if your distribution is [fat tailed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_5WwBkq6oo), but I doubt this is a problem in your case.

Comment: @Sycorax i think im paranoid here, feels weird just fitting models with raw data without processing when it looks unbalanced for me.

Comment: Also i already did a lot of different preprocessing attempts like minmax/standard scaling, removing outliers, normalizing, removing some features which had some multicollinearity - every time the result was a bit worse/same than without preprocessing

Comment: You can still apply centering & scaling to the data, despite the histogram ... you can compute a $z$-score, for instance, because the data has some mean and a positive standard deviation.